# JAXB: How to exclude specific field from marshaling in runtime?

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, cxf, jettison

I'm using JAXB+Jettison to serve multiformat RESTful (schema-less) service.
`@XmlTransient` annotation served good for those properties that I don't want to serialize at all. But that's not enough.

How can I exclude specific field from marshaling **in runtime**?

Can I somehow preinitialize Marshaling context and define what fields to exclude?

I need that to selectively serialize object fields based on current user's role.

Comment: "How can I exclude specific field from marshaling in runtime?" - Could you provide us with a reason why you want to do this? If you want optional attributes, that's possible, which would serve the same purpose.

Comment: Hi Jeff! Thanks for your input! I updated my question (the last line). I hope it makes it clear that `optional` annotation value is not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done similar before by having a number of DTOs in a hierarchy, from lean to full fat, each with differing JAXB mappings. However this is only practical for a small number of roles.

[MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) does allow runtime binding alterations, seems to fit the bill for your use-case.

However, beware with tampering with your service contracts, it can lead to weird live bugs that are a PAIN to track down.

Comment: Thank you Jeff! Yes, `n*roles` of DTOs is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm actually using MOXy to resolve circular object graph and I was trying to google within its documentation for subj - didn't find anything. Can you suggest some keywords or a particular doc link?

Comment: Here is an example: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/moxy-extensible-models-refresh-example.html

Comment: Thank you! Apparently this one http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/RefreshMetadata is an official copy of the one you provided.

Comment: +1 for MOXy.  We also offer JSON binding support in MOXy this gives you the option of dropping Jettison.